# Is there a disadvantage to using boost::interprocess::interprocess_semaphore within a single multithreaded c++ process?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

The disadvantage would be in comparison to a technique that was specialized to work on threads that are running within the same process. For example, does wait/post cause the whole process to yield, rather than just the executing thread, even though anyone waiting for a post would be within the same process?

The semaphore would be used, for example, to solve a producer/consumer problem in a shared buffer between two threads in the same process.

Are there any reasonable alternatives?

Comment: see http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2007/11/32207.php for a discussion of the problem

Comment: Yes, I'm using threads, but apparently boost does not support semaphores that are optimized to be shared only within a single process. You have to essentially implement semaphores yourself by using mutexes, condition variables, and integer counters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Boost.Thread condition variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) as shown [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401518;jsessionid=RNJXDZDS1K4SHQE1GHPCKHWATMY32JVN?pgno=5). The accompanying article has a good summary of Boost.Thread features.

Using interprocess semaphores will work but it's likely to place a tax on your execution due to use of unnecessarily heavyweight underlying OS locking primitives (named kernel objects in Windows, for example).